# How to catch return value from service method?

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I am completely new to silverlight and WCF. Still reading online stuff and trying to write some code to get going. :)

My question is, I want to insert data into database and my insert method returns a bool. How would I catch the return value in silverlight in the button click event and display confirmation message to the user.

My Service code is:

```
[OperationContract]
    public bool insertData(string Name, string Address, string cType, string postcode, string city, string phone, string email)
    {
        bussAppDataContext dc = new bussAppDataContext();
        TestTable tt = new TestTable();


        tt.CompanyName = Name;
        tt.Address = Address;
        tt.CompanyType = cType;
        tt.Postcode = postcode;
        tt.City = city;
        tt.Telephone = phone;
        tt.Email = email;

        dc.TestTables.InsertOnSubmit(tt);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
        return true;

    }
```

And the silverlight client code is:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FirstServiceReference.FirstServiceClient webServc = new FirstServiceReference.FirstServiceClient();
```

webServc.insertDataAsync(txtCName.Text.Trim(), txtAddress.Text.Trim(), cmbCType.SelectedValue.ToString(), txtPostcode.Text.Trim(), txtCity.Text.Trim(), txtPhone.Text.Trim(), txtEmail.Text.Trim());

}

Answer (score 2):

all webservice calls are async in silverlight so you need to add a handler to the insertDataCompleted event. This event is called when the operation is done.
Something like this:

```
webServc.insertDataCompleted += MyHandler;
webServc.insertDataAsync(txtCName.Text.Trim(), txtAddress.Text.Trim(), cmbCType.SelectedValue.ToString(), txtPostcode.Text.Trim(), txtCity.Text.Trim(), txtPhone.Text.Trim(), txtEmail.Text.Trim());

}

private void MyHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs args) {}
```

The args have the boolean as result.
Have a look here [Calling web services with Silverlight Tim Heuer](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/03/14/calling-web-services-with-silverlight-2.aspx).

Hope this helps.

BR,

TJ

Comment: I guess you can generate the handler by typing webServc.insertDataCompleted += and then hit TAB TAB...

Comment: Hi. My handler shows an error.  webServc.insertDataCompleted += new EventHandler<insertDataCompletedEventArgs>(webServc_insertDataCompleted); The error is: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler<ServiceReference.BussAppTest.Web.Services.FirstService.insertDataCompletedEventArgs>' to 'System.EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>' C:\Users\R730\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\BussAppTest\BussAppTest\Views\Home.xaml.cs 55 45 BussAppTest

Comment: Ok, try to change the event args of the handler to the type System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs. Then check what type the event args have for real. Have you let VisualStudio generate your completed handler?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If you want you can sent me your source and i'll have a look at it. Maybe something went wrong with generating the stubs...

Comment: I have not solved my problem. I still have the error. So I rather used System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs -method.